# How to remove all traces of SO from Chrome

Tags: authentication

I've just upgraded my MacBook, and tried to get up and running on SO again.

Seems I have TWO SO accounts, a main one (this) and a mistake-one (with almost no activity).  Unfortunately I used "Google Login" & the mistake-one is paired with my Google account, so I get that one.

I can't see any way to logout and login again as the correct account.

The only way I can get to THIS account is through an incognito window (which I'm currently doing).

It's a serious usability concern, I think.  I really am absolutely stuck.

I don't want to completely remove ALL of my Chrome history & fresh-start.

What to do?

PS At risk of bundling two questions into one, I would like to delete my dud account & relink THIS one with my current Google account. Is this doable?

PPS I know this belongs on the Meta, but I had my meta account disabled about 10 years ago, and unfortunately there seems to be no expiry date on that.

Comment: Use the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of this page for your account concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally fix this by deleting all cookies pertaining to Stack Overflow.

Go in to your Chrome `Preferences` and search for "Cookies".

It's actually in:

```
Preferences 
-> Privacy and security 
-> Site settings 
-> Cookies 
-> See all cookies and site data 
-> (Filter for "Stack")
-> (remove StackOverflow / StackExchange cookies)
```

Next time I visited https://stackoverflow.com, I was given the option to login, And when I clicked it Chrome auto-remembered my (correct) user/pass so I didn't even have to fish those out.